# How to check if values in array are greater than using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have departments. In each department there are several name panels. If a department has more than 3 panel names then give me a notification in which department.

I'm iterating over the departments and push the panel length to an array.
Now I should make something like `$.inArray()` if there is a value in array that matches just return me the index. But unfortunately I have no idea how to check for multiple values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $countDepartmentPanels = [];
  $("div[id^=department-]").each(function(index, value) {
    $countDepartmentPanels.push(value.children.length);
  });

  console.log($countDepartmentPanels);
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="department-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 1.1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 1.2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 1.3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="department-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 2.1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 2.2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 2.3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 2.4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="department-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 3.1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 3.2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="department-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 4.1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 4.2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 4.3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 4.4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">Name 4.5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39760/)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, or even what the issue you're trying to solve is.

Comment: okey i have the solution `console.log($.map($countDepartmentPanels, function(element, index){
  
   if(element < 4) {
     return index;
    }`

Comment: I don't see how that's a solution, but ok. If that's what you need you can do the check in the `each()` and remove the need for the second loop via `map()`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thank you for this hint i removed the `.map()` function and made a if in `.each()` now its working without the map

Answer (score 0):

Try this .Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39766/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $countDepartmentPanels = [],indexArray=[];

    $("div[id^=department-]").each(function(index, value) {

    $countDepartmentPanels.push(value.children.length);

  }); 
  $countDepartmentPanels.map(function(value,index){
         if(value > 2){
        indexArray.push({index: index,value:value})

       }
  })
  console.log($countDepartmentPanels);
  console.log(indexArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get appropriate indexes of `countDepartmentPanels` where value greater then 3:

```
var departmentsIdxs = [];
countDepartmentPanels.forEach(function(cdp, i) {
    if (cdp > 3) {
        departmentsIdxs.push(i);
    }
})
```

And here is fork from your example: https://jsfiddle.net/2ghdxfvr/

Hope this helps